# systemd: send SIGTERM twice with delay, *then* send SIGKILL?

Tags: systemd

Is there some way I can get systemd to behave like this:

1. Send SIGTERM
2. Wait 2 minutes
3. Send SIGTERM again
4. Wait 2 minutes
5. Send SIGKILL

Step 1, 2 and 5 are easy enough as that means only adjusting TimeoutStopSec but I don't see any way to accomplish 3 and 4. Possible?

Comment: That's not really a programming question, check out e.g. superuser.com instead, but that time make sure to *first* read the guidelines there.

Answer (score 0):

Using custom `ExecStop` commands:

```sh
ExecStop=kill $MAINPID
ExecStop=sleep 120
ExecStop=kill $MAINPID
ExecStop=sleep 120
ExecStop=kill -KILL $MAINPID
```